# Scrollbar position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollbar

My question is related the following fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/PGuB5/84/

In this fiddle, Click the **add row** button, the row will be added. The scroll bar will be displayed automatically after some content added.

```
$('.scrollToBottom').on('click', function() {
    $(".scrollbox").scrollTop($(".scrollbox")[0].scrollHeight);
});
```

Now I scroll the content at the bottom of the container and click the **add row** button. The scroll bar position is stay in the bottom.

I want, If I click the **add row** button, the scroll bar need to move to top.

Comment: Is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/PGuB5/299/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scrolling to top, use :

```
$('.scrollbox').scrollTop(0);
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PGuB5/299/)**

```
$('.addrow').on('click', function() {
    $('.scrollbox').append(newline);
    $('.scrollbox').scrollTop(0);
});
```

Comment: yeah. I will implement it and let you know.